# Fetch wordpress text editor content to core php

Tags: php, wordpress, text

I want to fetch WordPress text area editor from WordPress and use it in core PHP code, where WordPress is not installed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Fahad!

I'm afraid you can't access WP editor without making your PHP as WP child. However, you can use the same editor used by WordPress.

WordPress is using TinyMCE editor. You can find numerous tutorials over internet to integrate TinyMCE in your PHP. You can see [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/howto/TinyMCE3x@How-to_implement_TinyMCE_in_PHP/) or [here](https://www.skptricks.com/2018/03/add-tinymce-editor-in-php-or-html.html) to get start with.

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I was a little doubt about your question.

**1 - Using PHP editor without using WP**

To use you can use the TinyMCE link to the documentation site: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/TinyMCE3x@Installation/

There are a few other editors you can use:

```
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
https://ckeditor.com/
https://summernote.org/
```

**2 - Using WordPress as Backend**

In case if you want to use WordPress and just order the content but without estart using wordpress, you can get it by API.
Example: ..... site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

For more information: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/